# Modular routes in python flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to have one service which will fulfill two related functions. I would like to have something like this for my REST api:

```
/route1/get/as_text

/route2/get/as_json
```

In nodejs, you can pass off a collection of routes from some base URL by saying:

```
app.use('/route1/', route1.js)
app.use('/route2/', route2.js)
```

and then the `route1.js` will have routes defined like this:

```
app.router('/as_text', function(){//some stuff})
```

When I do this, can define a set of routes, that all have `/route1/` as the basis of the URL. I would like to do something similar in flask, where I just define the first section of the url, and add all logic of that section of the API into a file which is separate to another section of the api.

Is this possible in flask? Or should I look for a new approach?

Comment: I'm not sure whether *flask* has some built-in support for that (expecting an answer), but you definitely could register route to `'/route/get/<response_type>'` and then serve different data depending on `response_type` value. You could even make a decoroator which configures the route *and* serves one type or the other automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/).

When defining your application, you can register Blueprints with a path prefix:

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='views')
app.register_blueprint(controllers.route1, url_prefix="/route1")
app.register_blueprint(controllers.route2, url_prefix="/route2")
```

Then define the controllers for these routes in separate files.

```
route1 = Blueprint('route1', __name__, template_folder='views')

@route1.route('/get/as_text',methods=['GET'])
def get_as_text_route():

    return json.jsonify(data="my data")
```

You could also checkout [Flask Restful](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.4/) for creating REST APIs in with Flask.